# How to get an adress of a static array in C

Tags: c, arrays

Got this

```
char array1[10][10];
```

Is it possible to get address of array1 ? In which type could I stock it ?
Already tried the following:

```
char *hold[10][10];
hold = &array1;
```

But doesnt work, ideas?

Comment: Try: `char (*hold)[10][10] = &array1;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you want to get the address of the first element, not a pointer to a  2D array. The first element is a `char [10]` (a 1D array), so you need

```
char (*hold)[10] = array1;
```

Notice `array1` is converted to a pointer to the first element for the assignment. This is **not** recursively applied!

That way you can dereference the pointer exactly like for the original array:

```
hold[4][5]
```

For the `char (*hold)[10][10]` approach, the syntax is more complicated and not really ideomatic. Accessing an element of the array would require dereferencing the pointer first:

```
(*hold)[4][5]
```

Answer (score 3):

What you have now is a 2D array of `char *`.  You need some parenthesis in this type.

```
char (*hold)[10][10];
```

This is a pointer to a 2D array of type `char[10][10]` that you can assign `&array` to.

Comment: I imagine I can't assign directly an array to another array? Need to use pointers?

Comment: @Romain-p: You can do only few things with an array without using a pointer actually. However, you might want to have a look at my answer. It is more idenomatic for what you likely want.